# Fary-Milnor Theorem : Help following a proof on page 9

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, curvature

I am studying [Fary-Milnor Theorem](http://mduchin.math.tufts.edu/UCD/116/milnor.pdf) on total curvature of knots and I am stuck in a proof. He is proving on page 9:

> The Total curvature of a tame knot cannot equal the curvature of its type

k(C) := total curvature of knot C

So by assuming false he takes a knot C which k(C)=k([C])
(where [C] := it's isotopic equivalence class) and gets the inscribed polygon, P,which is a member of [C] (proved existence in theorem 4.2 on page 8) 
he create another polygon in [C], P', which have the property of
k(P') < k(P) <= k(C) = k([C]).
and write "which is impossible".
I cannot see why it is impossible. Can someone help?

[milnor proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzSV7.png)

Thanks,

Comment: Who is "he"? What is the source?

Comment: just edited added milnor proof which I am studying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the OP's reference is Milnor's paper:

*Milnor, John W.*, [**On the total curvature of knots**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1969467), Ann. Math. (2) 52, 248-257 (1950). [ZBL0037.38904](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0037.38904).

Secondly, the total curvature of a type is the inf of the curvatures of tame knots of that isotopy type. Milnor shows (using proposition 1.2 in [the paper](http://people.reed.edu/~ormsbyk/milnor-total-curvature.pdf)), that you can always decrease the curvature slightly by an isotopy, so the inf is never attained.